# I Have a column in my database called name and I want to check 2 condition if the name is already exist and if it doesn't exist insert to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

this the html with ajax and it displays successful and inserts into the database but how can I display error message if the name is already exist after the validation

```
<form action="" id="manage-project">
```

```
                <label for="" class="control-label">Project Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="name"  value="<?php echo isset($name) ? $name : '' ?>">
            </div>
<div class="card-footer border-top border-info">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <button class="btn btn-flat  bg-gradient-primary mx-2" form="manage-project">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-flat bg-gradient-secondary mx-2" type="button" onclick="location.href='index.php?page=project_list'">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
$('#manage-project').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    start_load()
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php?action=save_project',
        data: new FormData($(this)[0]),   

        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        method: 'POST',
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(resp){
            if(resp == 1){
                alert_toast('Data successfully saved',"success");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.href = 'index.php?page=project_list'
                },2000)
            }
        }
    })
```

This is the  insertion query and I guess I need select query to validate the name. help me out here

```
function save_project(){
    extract($_POST);
    $data = "";
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
        if(!in_array($k, array('id','user_ids')) && !is_numeric($k)){
            if($k == 'description')
                $v = htmlentities(str_replace("'","&#x2019;",$v));
            if(empty($data)){
                $data .= " $k='$v' ";
            }else{
                $data .= ", $k='$v' ";
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($user_ids)){
        $data .= ", user_ids='".implode(',',$user_ids)."' ";
    }
    if(empty($id)){
        $save = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO project_list set $data");
    }else{
        $save = $this->db->query("UPDATE project_list set $data where id = $id");
    }
    if($save){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$check = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM project_list where name ='$name' ".(!empty($id) ? " and id != {$id} " : ''))->num_rows;
    if($check > 0){
        return 2;
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get your javascript error message ready

```
let data = { name: $('#manage-project input[name="name"]').val() } ;
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax.php?action=save_project',
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  method: 'post',
  success: function(resp) {
    if (resp == 1) {
      alert_toast('Data successfully saved', "success");
      setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = 'index.php?page=project_list'
      }, 2000)
    } else {
      alert_toast('Error, name already exists', "error");
    }
  }
})
```

and in your php, we can use the codeigniter style syntax which will bind our query safely

```
 function save_project() {
     extract($_POST);

     // FOR TESTING ONLY - REMOVE WHEN THIS SHOWS THE RIGHT RESPONSE
     $query = "select * from project_list where LOWER(name) = '".trim($_POST['name']).
     "'";
     if (isset($_POST['id']) $query. = " AND id != ".$_POST['id']; $exists = $this - > db - > query($query) - > result(); die("Found rows: ".count($exists).
             " from query: ".$query);


     // Straight MySQL - this should work
     $query = "select * from project_list where LOWER(name) = '".trim($_POST['name']).
     "'";
     if (isset($_POST['id']) $query. = " AND id != ".$_POST['id']; $exists = $this - > db - > query($query) - > num_rows() > 0;

     // The CI way of doing it
     /*   
       $this->db->select('*');    
       $this->db->where('LOWER(name)', strtolower($name));
       if (!empty($id)) $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
       $exists = $this->db->count_all_results("project_list")>0;
     */
     if ($exists) { die('0'); } $data = ""; foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
         if (!in_array($k, array('id', 'user_ids')) && !is_numeric($k)) {
             if ($k == 'description')
                 $v = htmlentities(str_replace("'", "&#x2019;", $v));
             if (empty($data)) {
                 $data. = " $k='$v' ";
             } else {
                 $data. = ", $k='$v' ";
             }
         }
     }
     if (isset($user_ids)) {
         $data. = ", user_ids='".implode(',', $user_ids).
         "' ";
     }
     if (empty($id)) {
         $save = $this - > db - > query("INSERT INTO project_list set $data");
     } else {
         $save = $this - > db - > query("UPDATE project_list set $data where id = $id");
     }
     if ($save) {
         return 1;
     }
 }
```

Note, we're `die`ing the result. Ajax requires output to be echoed back to the client, not `return`ed

Comment: Thanks Kinglish but should i remove the existing php code and replace with this code or where should I add this code?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can do it right after `extract($_POST);`

Comment: No, no. this is an addition to your code. It just escapes early if you try and submit an insert with a name that already exists, or an update with a new name but that name already exists.

Comment: That's great. Please mark as the answer. Cheers

Comment: alright only the error message worked . even it doesn't insert into database when new value is entered it displays error. whats the problem

Comment: my bad, I forget num_rows was a function...  `$exists = $this->db->get("project_list")->num_rows()>0;` answer updated

Comment: Also, for the success part,  change to `if($save){ die('1'); }` - your ajax won't read a `return`

Comment: still the same probelm bro it displays error

Comment: Ok, just to make sure I understand: Before updating or inserting you want to be sure that the incoming project's name does not already exist in the projecs database, is that right?

Comment: If the project name exists I wanted to display "the name already exist"   and if it doesn't exist I wanted it to insert into the database successfully

Comment: again, I forgot the ->select() (actually I didn't think it mattered here). Can you try the updated answer? Thanks

Comment: Wow, ok. I updated the answer to be regular SQL in case I've got something wrong with the CI syntax. Can you try it? If this doesn't work, please check to make sure the POST you're sending through has name (and ID if its an update), and also that there really isn't a database row with the same name. Just want to be sure to rule that out.

Comment: I've checked all things there is no row with same name also the POST method... do you think the problem is on the SQL?

Comment: OK. check out the revised answer. I put a die() statement in there to show you the number of matches it finds and the actual query statement that's running. Please try that and let me know the output you get in the browser web inspector. thx

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you said. I'm using xampp where should I run the query and what browser web inspector?

Comment: Yes, this is all being done through ajax so if you want to see what the server is returning, view the network tab in the inspector: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/website/how-to-inspect-and-change-style-using-google-chrome

Comment: come to think of it, I thought you were checking this the whole time... lol. This is how you troubleshoot ajax - through the web inspector. It can show you what your outgoing POST variables are and what the server response is. It is really something you should get to know :)

Comment: Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK

Comment: Ok I have updated your whole ajax function, including setting the data object. Your form doesn't have any ID element so I didn't put that into the data {} tag. I also updated to show the whole `save_project` function. When the ajax goes to `ajax.php`, I assume you have something like `if ($_GET['action']=='save_project') save_project();`

Comment: bro it worked with this code $check = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM project_list where name ='$name' ".(!empty($id) ? " and id != {$id} " : ''))->num_rows;
  if($check > 0){
   return 2;
   exit;
  }